# How to insert a running header, but not on the first page

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering

I am writing a CV in LaTeX and I want my name as a running header on the top of each page. I used the simple command:

```
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\markright{Name}
```

However, I do not want the header to appear on the first page. How can I remove it?

Also, is there a way to keep the page number on the bottom of each page? When I use the above comment in `article` document class, it moves the page number to the top right-hand corner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about using `fancyhdr`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titling}
\author{You}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[R]{\theauthor}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\thispagestyle{empty}

Write your CV here
\end{document}
```

This should give the result you expect. Note also that there exist many document classes written specifically for CVs, like the popular `moderncv` which has its own tag here.